# HTML Code for a short horizontal line centered next to certain text

Tags: html, text, line, horizontal-line

I'm looking for the HTML code to create a short horizontal line centered inline with text (in a particular typeface) like the image.
[image]

Currently, the code I have is:

```
<span style="font-family:'Taner Ardali Antikor Mono Medium';">MY MISSION</span>
```

Note: I'm using this code for a text markdown or code block on my Squarespace site. I'm unfamiliar with coding, so not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:after` selector for this

```css
.title {
  font-family:'Taner Ardali Antikor Mono Medium';
  font-size: 30px;
  display: block;
}
.title:after {
  content:"";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background: #111;
  vertical-align: super;
}
```

```html
<span class="title">MY MISSION</span>
```

**Or** It is possible to change HTML use heading tag like this:

```css
.title {
  font-family:'Taner Ardali Antikor Mono Medium';
  font-size: 30px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.title span {
   background: #fff;
       position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.title:after {
  content:"";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background: #111;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title"><span>MY MISSION</span></h2>
```

Comment: I'm using this code for a text markdown or code block on my Squarespace site. I'm unfamiliar with coding, but it doesn't seem to work.